Unable to properly set roles during migration
In a Drupal 7 to Drupal 10 migration, I am unable to set role for some users.
After migrating a Drupal 7 website to Drupal 10 using Migrate module, user roles are not properly saved.
Neither the web Interface nor the Drush command seem to work.
If I assign the administrator role to a user, the role will be granted and listed on the People page. However, if I return to the User edit page, the Administrator role is not assigned. drush user:information –uid=<uid> --fields=roles does not return the expected role.
No error displayed and no log entry either.
Is there any way to rebuild roles and permissions, or did I miss some settings?

I tried to apply this patch from this comment. Applying the patch did not solved the problem. It might be related to CiviCRM since the module is installed and enabled. Maybe my migration process is involved. Role from newly created accounts can be successfully edited. The main issue is that I don't find any clue to start with, even in the logs. Even when using Devel, I don't fully understand what is happening when I press the submit button.
